# Hibernate Tools - DAO generation

Tags: java, hibernate, dao, hibernate-tools

I am using the eclipse hibernate tools plug-in to reverse engineer my database.
I spent my whole day looking for how to force the DAO generator to use HQL/Criteria with the session factory, transaction, etc.

Right now, if I have the table TABLE in my database, I obtain the DAO class TableHome. This class uses the persistence EntityManager.

I found tutorials using an older version of hibernate tools generating TableDAO instead, and this is what I exactly need.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Is it: "How do you force the DAO generator to use HQL/Criteria with the session factory, transaction, etc.?"

Comment: Yes, I would like to force the DAO generator to use HQL/Criteria with the session factory, transaction, etc instead of the EntityManager.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you're using Eclipse or not is unclear but if you are, maybe check if the **Console Configuration** used by the **Code Generation** module is not configured for JPA:

[alt text http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html/images/plugins/plugins_2.png](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html/images/plugins/plugins_2.png)

#### See also

- Section [3.4. Creating a Hibernate Console Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html#console_conf)
- Section [3.5. Reverse Engineering and Code Generation](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html#d0e890)

Comment: Yes, "Core" is selected.

I took a look into my Hibernate.jar and I found the template file used for my entities. And it is the JPA one !

So my problem becomes, how to change this template ?
I am currently searching.

Comment: @Julio No template for pure Hibernate?

Comment: No and I finally made my DAOs myself :)

Comment: Use Salto-DB Eclipse plugin. It comes with all the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use Salto-DB Eclipse plugin. It comes with all the stuff.