# Generating DAO with Hibernate Tools on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, dao, hibernate-tools

How can I use the tools to generate DAOs?

In fact, instead of passing through the `hbm` files, I need to configure hibernate tools to generate the DAO and the annotations.

See [Hibernate Tools - DAO generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952807/hibernate-tools-dao-generation) and [How generate DAO with Hibernate Tools in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251124/how-generate-dao-with-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me assume DAO as POJO/Entity beans.  Basically you can accomplish your task either through forward or reverse engineering. In case of forward engineering, probably you can look into AndroMDA tool. In case If u wish to accomplish it through reverse engineering Click [here](http://srinivaskarthik.blog.com/2012/11/23/generating-entity-filespojo-using-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse/) ..

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to add a query in the DAO, could you give how?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome.  You got to write all your data access logic by your hand (if I’m not wrong).  Hiberante let you interact with database in three ways.

1. **Native SQL** which is nothing but DDL/plain SQL query. This can be used very rarely in hibernate projects even though this is faster than below mentioned options. Reason is simple “One of the key advantage of hibernate or any other popular ORM framework over JDBC Is you can get rid of database specific queries from your application code!”
2. **HQL** stands for hibernate query language which is proprietary query language of hibernate. This looks similar to native SQL queries but the key difference is object/class name will be used instead of table name and public variable names will be used instead of column names. This is more Object oriented approach. Some interesting things will be happening in background and check if you are keen!
3. **Criteria** API is a more object oriented and elegant alternative to Hibernate Query Language (HQL). It’s always a good solution to an application which has many optional search criteria.

You can find lots of examples on internet. Please post your specific requirements for further clarification on your problem.

Cheers!